# Relation between two lists in Java

Tags: java

I have two sets of different types of objects. Each element of one set is related to one element of the other, and the two lists are in two different classes.

I have a function that iterates over one set and check if this element must be removed, and when it does I must delete the associated element in the other set.

What kind of collection and methodology must I use to do so?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a Map instead of 2 Lists?

Comment: If the elements of the first set are hashable, then a `HashMap` will let you remove bits of an isomorphism.

Comment: I need two lists because each list is in a different class. I will edit my question stating this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation described sounds like a good fit for using a `Set` in Java (not a `List`). For example:

```
// s1 contains the set {1, 4, 5, 3}
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.add(1); s1.add(4); s1.add(5); s1.add(3);

// s2 contains the set {1, 2, 3}
Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s2.add(1); s2.add(2); s2.add(3);

// perform the difference between s1 and s2
s1.removeAll(s2);

// now s1 contains the set {4, 5}
System.out.println(s1);
=> [4, 5]
```

**UPDATE**

If both sets contain elements of different types, then you must devise a way to convert from one type to the other, or as you put it in the question: to find the "associated element in the other set". This can be a straightforward conversion, or maybe a `Map` holding the relationships in such a way that given an element of the first set you can quickly obtain the corresponding element from the second set. For example, if a conversion suffices:

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.add(1); s1.add(4); s1.add(5); s1.add(3);

Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
s2.add("1"); s2.add("2"); s2.add("3");

for (String s : s2) {
    // find "associated element"
    Integer n = Integer.valueOf(s);
    if (s1.contains(n))
        s1.remove(n);
}
```

If a simple conversion is not possible, then the plan B is to define a mapping between elements:

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.add(1); s1.add(4); s1.add(5); s1.add(3);

Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
s2.add("1"); s2.add("2"); s2.add("3");

// map the equivalences from one set into the other
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("1", 1);
map.put("2", 2);
map.put("3", 3);

for (String s : s2) {
    // find "associated element"
    Integer n = map.get(s);
    if (s1.contains(n))
        s1.remove(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about performance, go for the solution provided with `Set`. Keep in mind it has `Om^2` time complexity.

As mentioned in the comments, there is a way to implement that using `Map`, which will provide you with a `Om` solution (depending on how it is implemented).

```
class Relationship<T, V> {
    final T o1;
    final V o1;

    public Relationship(o1, o2) {
        this.o1 = o1;
        this.o2 = o2;
    }
}

Map<String, Relationship> relationship = new Map<>;

// create the relationships add it to the Map instead to a List
relations.put("id12", new Relationship(o1, o2));
relations.put("id34", new Relationship(o3, o4));

// ...

// iterate over `relationships` and remove if its necessary.
```